# Excel Data Validation between Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of ID's and Descriptions in Sheet 1. This data is then used in a second sheet (Sheet 2) which the user can interact with.

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

The list in Sheet 1, has an ID which repeats, but has a different description. How would I be able to use data validation in Sheet 2 to combine all the repeats of ID number 4 into 1, but allow the user to select the description (using a drop down box) they desire, after the selection in Column A is made?

I would like to stay away from Macros for this - only using in-built functions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Combine the repeats in Sheet1. Lookup formulas return only the first found value, so if you have multiples of the same ID, you will need to create a lookup with unique IDs instead. Prepare that in a helper table and use the helper table for the data validation if you don't want to or cannot change the original table.

It is quite misleading that an identifier (which is called that for a reason) is not unique.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! What if I am not able to adjust the Sheet so that there are unique ID's? I understand it's misleading but it's part of the problem :)

Comment: You'll need a helper table, as I explained in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the version of Excel you are using. I suggest a possible solution based on my understanding of your question.  It however also uses a functions named IFERROR & COUNTBLANK that I suppose are not available before Excel 2007. So in case you have Excel 2003 a different approach may be required.

This might not be very ideal solution as it uses helper columns and also a helper sheet!

In this example sample data is in Sheet1!A2:B10 as seen in this screenshot.

First we need to create a helper column in Column D to get the unique list from your IDs.

In D2 put the following formula and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. You also need to leave a row (preferably first row) as header for this to work correctly.

The formula shall be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

Drag it down till intended rows based on the expected count of unique values in your master column. Eventually it will start returning blanks at the bottom, then you may stop. This creates a Unique Master List of IDs.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $A$2:$A$10), 0)),"")
```

[image]

Now we need to know the exact start and end of this list to populate the Validation List.

Now in G3 put the following formula.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D2:D10,1)
```

and in G4 put the following Array Formula.

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet1!D2:D10="",ROW(Sheet1!D2:D10),9^99))-2
```

Don't forget <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for this one.

Now go to Name Manager and create a new Name called MyList

Put the following formula therein

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10,Sheet1!$G$3):INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10,Sheet1!$G$4)
```

Here we use INDEX to return a Cell Reference rather than a Value

[image]

Insert a new Sheet named Sheet2.

Now in Col A2 and below create a Validation List and put `=MyList` therein.

Now all unique Values feature in the first drop down list for IDs.
[image]

[image]

This completes Part1.

Now the next task is to populate a second validation list based on data extracted from Description Column.

Insert a third helper sheet called Sheet3. You can simply hide this sheet.

In this example I have taken data in Sheet3!B2:H10. Decide the number of columns based on the max number of duplicates in your IDs from master list. Also leave first Column A for this to work correctly.

In B2 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create and Array Formula.

Drag it down across and below as intended.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10, SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)-1,999),COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2))),"")
```

[image]
Back in Name Manager create a new name called Trimmed and put the following formula therein.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet3!$B1,0,0):OFFSET(Sheet3!$B1,0,COUNTA(Sheet3!$B1:$H1)-COUNTBLANK(Sheet3!$B1:$H1)-1)
```

This generates a list excluding blanks so that the List is properly trimmed.

[image]

Now in Sheet2 for Cells B2 and down create a Validation List and put `=Trimmed` therein.
[image]

Now as your data changes in Sheet1!A2:A10 the list of Unique Values get reflected automatically in MyList and also then the name Trimmed will fetch only the intended Description from the Sheet1 Description column.

See the below Screen to GIF to get a feel how the whole thing  works.
[image]